# Should there be a badge for cheating

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Reading the [extended FAQ on badges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135647/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow) I recognize the rules for losing badges. There are two of them and both are completely justified.

But, considering, that this is about Tech and Coding and Wizz, shouldn't there be a badge for "Cheating". This badge should be awarded if someone cheated the site (reputation/badge/vote system) in a creative, successful and funny way. For example someone receives the Populist-badge without having outscored another answer. Obviously he loses this badge, either if caught or because he turned himself in. Especially in the latter case he could also have the badge "Cheater" assigned in return. (Generally as a cheating case will always need human intervention, this badge is not automatically assigned.)

A Cheater-badge probably should be a gold badge because the cheater beat stackoverflow and not some fool's homepage.

Well, actually the badge should only be awarded if the cheater turns himself in, reveals the cheating technique and generally helps to improve the site.

Comment: -1 This does **not** encourage positive behavior.

Comment: That Question was not Worth -5.. Well a +1 From Me...

Comment: +1 to this question. Hacking attempts should not be feared of, in fact they should be welcomed. Security by obscurity is not the way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a super secret badge that is handed out to users who are exemplary in their service to the sites (such as discovering and helping correct a security vulnerability). This is [the "hacker" badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/). Perhaps you could attain for that instead.

Comment: Has this ever actually been awarded?

Comment: I do not believe so Kyle.

Comment: Actually that very much is what I searched for.

Comment: Shouldn't this be added to the [list of badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/162705)?

Answer (score 15):

No.

Questionable behaviour should not be rewarded in any way.

Comment: I seem to be misunderstood here. The emphasis should have been on "disclosing the way of cheating-possibilities by PoC", which, AFAIK is the usual way of improvement in application security (and general debugging).

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. Badges are specifically for behavior that we want to encourage.
2. We want to encourage *professional* behavior, not behavior that games the site.

So, no.  That said, if you find an "unusual" exploit and report it you can already earn a the "hidden" Hacker badge.

Comment: Has this ever actually been awarded?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bad idea, but it has been declined. As others have said, what you call a "cheating" badge basically describes the Hacker badge. Well, the Hacker badge "was never implemented and probably won't be at this point" according to [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104414/131713) on Sep 11, 2011.